# How to use friends.get()?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to make further use of the API by obtaining the list of our user's friends and displaying their details in my application.
in old version, I  use
 `$facebook->api_client->friends_get` 
and
 `$facebook->api_client->users_getInfo`
But in facebook 2012,i don't know how to use?
some body help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sample:

```
<?
      // Remember to copy files from the SDK's src/ directory to a
      // directory in your application on the server, such as php-sdk/
      require_once('src/facebook.php');

      $config = array(
        'appId' => '*******',
        'secret' => '************',
      );

      $facebook = new Facebook($config);
      $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
    ?>
    <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>

      <?
    if(empty($user_id)){
        $dialog_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
           . $GLOBALS['config']['appid'] . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)."&scope=friends_hometown";
        echo ("<script> top.location.href='".$dialog_url ."' </script>");
    }
          // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
          // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
          try {
            $fql = 'SELECT pic_square,hometown_location,name,sex FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())';
            $ret_obj = $facebook->api(array(
                                       'method' => 'fql.query',
                                       'query' => $fql,
                                     ));
    $count=count($ret_obj);
    echo '<pre>';
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    echo 'Name: ' . $ret_obj[$i]['name'];
    echo '<br />';
    echo 'Sex:'   . $ret_obj[$i]['sex'];
    echo '<br />';
    echo 'Home :'   . $ret_obj[$i]['hometown_location']['city'];
    echo '<br />';  
    }
            // FQL queries return the results in an array, so we have
            //  to get the user's name from the first element in the array.
            echo'</pre>';

          } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
            error_log($e->getType());
            error_log($e->getMessage());
          }   

      ?>

      </body>
    </html>
```

---

you can use php Sdk 
& to get Friends of users 
use this code

```
$friends=$facebook->api('me/friends/,'GET');
```

& about information it depends on what information you want if you just want name & other very public infos the code above is enough

Comment: thank you,but "I want to make further use of the API by obtaining the list of our user's friends and displaying their details in my application".can you help me?

Comment: can you tell me what details you want ?

Comment: oh!my friend!i want to displaying Sex,name,and home.:).can you help me!

Comment: well, if you want hometown too its better you try fql , i will write a sample code for you
this is fql Command for what you want 
`SELECT pic_square,hometown_location,name,sex FROM user WHERE  uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())`
& this link to see a preview
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20pic_square%2Chometown_location%2Cname%2Csex%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20%20uid%20IN%20%28SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%20%3D%20me%28%29%29
wait for sample code

Comment: thank you very much.hixhix,i'm sorry,but how to display "sex" in my application??ah,what is your yahoo?:D